# Issue in parsing NSDictionay into JSON NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

How do we convert a NSDictionary into JSON data object? I want to send a JSON data to my server. I am using the below code but facing an issue when it comes to NSDictionary containing Array or further NSDictionary in it. This works well with simple key-value pair.

Issue: It fails on the below line and sets the error object. This works fine if I remove arrays and dictionaries from the source myData dictionary.

```
NSData *aPostBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myData options:0 error:&error];

Where myData looks like:

{
    URI = "www.google.com";
    addOnTestString = "4,3,";
    status =     (
            "In Progress",
            Submitted,
            Delivered
        );
data = 

{
    URI = "www.test.com";
    testString = "43";
    status =     (
            "In Progress",
            Submitted,
            Delivered
        );
}
}
```

Error trace:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my post. My error object is getting set and it fails in parsing the myData object.

Comment: And what are the contents of the error object? Please NSLog it.

Comment: Added the error trace here. Cannot log it on console. (lldb) po error
$1 = 0x0000000101053000 [no Objective-C description available]

Comment: Are you sure that's what your myData object looks like?  Maybe try setting myData explicitly to this test dictionary and see if you still get the error: `@{@"URI":@"www.google.com", @"addOnTestString":@"4,3,", @"status:":@[@"In Progress", @"Submitted", @"Delivered"], @"data":@{@"URI":@"www.test.com", @"testString":@"43", @"status":@[@"In Progress", @"Submitted", @"Delivered"]}};`

Comment: That's not a "trace" by the way. That's just the state of the stack in the current scope.

Comment: Have you checked that `aPostBodyData` is really `nil`? If no parsing error occurs, the value of `error` not set to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i just write a sample code that includes your situation and it works well.

```
  NSArray * myarray=@[@"a",@"b"];

        NSMutableDictionary * dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"a",myarray] forKeys:@[@"str",@"arr" ]];




        NSData * js=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];


        NSString * jsString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:js encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSLog(@"%@",jsString);
```

probable reasons for you get errors may be;

your myData is not in type NSDictionary or NSArray.

or while adding arrays to dictionary you are missing a point.